# mandreel c/c++ code compiling to js

Tags: javascript, c, web, coffeescript

Has anyone work on mandreel to convert/compile c/c++ code to javascript. I am try to make a website which can compile c/c++ code.

Is this approach correct. or coffeescript can help.